# Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms.View.SetContentProperty() Stackoverflow exception

Tags: xamarin.forms, caliburn.micro

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms app and trying to switch out views over the same viewmodel per the "Hello Screens" example. I've done this with CM in WPF several times successfully but it isn't working for me in Xamarin.Forms The ViewModel is "LessonsViewModel" with the following LessonsView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Caliburn.Micro.Platform.Xamarin.Forms"
             x:Class="MyCompany.FreshmanLevel.LessonView">
  <ContentView cal:View.Model="{Binding}" cal:View.Context="{Binding CurrentLesson, Mode=TwoWay}"></ContentView>
</ContentView>
```

LessonViewModel has a property called "CurrentLesson" which is an enum with the following possible values:

```
LessonOne
LessonTwo
LessonThree
```

I have a "Lesson" folder (i.e. "LessonViewModel" minus the "ViewModel") with the following xaml files

```
LessonOne.xaml
LessonTwo.xaml
LessonThree.xaml
```

If I use:

```
<ContentView cal:View.Model="{Binding}" cal:View.Context="LessonThree">
```

Everything works fine. But binding to a variable name like so:

```
<ContentView cal:View.Model="{Binding}" cal:View.Context="{Binding CurrentLesson, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Causes the following error which appears in the output console in VS:

```
Stack overflow: IP: 0x1213d7b05, fault addr: 0x0
at Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms.View.SetContentProperty (object,object) <IL 0x00019, 0x0016d>
at Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms.View.OnModelChanged (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject,Caliburn.Micro.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00033, 0x00258>
at Caliburn.Micro.DependencyPropertyHelper/<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<RegisterAttached>b__0 (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject,object,object) <IL 0x00017, 0x00132>
at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty,Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/BindablePropertyContext,object,bool,Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/SetValueFlags,bool) [0x00108] in C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:584
at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty,object,Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/SetValueFlags,Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/SetValuePrivateFlags) [0x0014b] in C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:378
at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.ApplyCore (object,Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject,Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty,bool) [0x0020c] in C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:177
at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.Apply (object,Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject,Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty) [0x0006b] in C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:76
at Xamarin.Forms.Binding.Apply (object,Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject,Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty) [0x00042]
 in C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Binding.cs:113
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Edit: From the best I can tell, the issue seems to stem from the fact that public property "CurrentLesson" isn't actually being read in as a result of the binding statement. I recreated the issue in a normal WPF application and realized that listing cal:View.Model="{Binding}" before cal:View.Context="{Binding CurrentLesson, Mode=TwoWay}" causes the issue in that case because the Context value needs to be read in prior to cal:View.Model being resolved.

However, I made that correction in my Xamarin Forms app and it still errors out. If I set a break point the cal:View.Context attached property is not even reading in the value of CurrentLesson before "OnContextChanged" is fired and so things error out in " static bool SetContentPropertyCore(object targetLocation, object view)"

Comment: u pass the enum or a string to that binding ?

Comment: Passing an enum which has the following values "LessonOne", "LessonTwo", "LessonThree"...  if I hardcode any one of these values without a binding statement, they work as expected.

Comment: So does that mean your Binding `CurrentLesson` that enum type ?

Comment: Correct.. CurrentLesson is a public property of the enum type

Comment: Well try to bind to a string instead and see if that helps !

Comment: Did it work for you ?!

Comment: No sorry it was taking me a while to respond. Holiday weekend. :) Yes, actually I tried that approach early on and it doesn't work when binding to a string. I get the same error. However, if I hardcode the string without a binding statement, it works. Whenever I set a breakpoint on the property field "CurrentLesson" what I'm seeing is that the binding statement is not reading in the value at all.

Comment: Okay ;( On binding errors always check these things: `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented, `BindingContext` is set correctly, check the `Output`window for any binding errors.